# Keep one nested div in HTML doc and clear all others

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to remove the cruft from a noisy, deeply nested HTML document. I'd like to keep the structure of the page, just clear the contents of the surrounding `div`s.

The structure is something like this:

```
<div class="a">
    ...stuff...
  <div>
   ...stuff....
    <div class="my_class_of_interest">
      ....several levels deeper...
      </div>
    ..stuff..
  </div>
  ...stuff..
</div>
```

I'd like to erase everything outside of the `div` I want, but keep everything within that `div`. This is the code I tried:

```
for div in soup.find_all("div"):
    if div.has_attr('class'):
        if div['class'] == "my_class_of_interest":
            continue
    div.clear()
```

But this erases my `div` of interest, I suspect because I am clearing its parent and the clearing goes all the way down. Is there a way to clear a `div`'s text without erasing nested `div`s? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `soup.find_all("div", class_="my_class_of_interest")`

Comment: I'd like to keep the structure of the page, just clear the contents of the surrounding `div`s.

Comment: The structure of the page is preserved as you are selecting divs only of interest to you

Comment: Just to confirm, you are basically interested in deleting all texts in the document, except the text in your target div?

Comment: yes. I've found just extracting the div seems to mess up the page, so I'd like to keep the structure and erase the other stuff and see if that helps

Comment: Then it's doable but not with beautifulsoup (or at least I couldn't figure out how to do that...) but with lxml, if that works for you.

Comment: @JackFleeting lxml would be great too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your question well. This script will erase all strings surrounding the tag of interest:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag


txt = '''
<div class="a">
  ...stuff...
  <div>
    ...stuff....
    <div class="my_class_of_interest">
      ....several levels deeper...
    </div>
  ..stuff..
  </div>
  ...stuff..
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

# print soup before clearing
print(soup)

def clear(tag):
    for c in tag.contents:
        if isinstance(c, Tag) and c.name == 'div' and 'my_class_of_interest' in c.get('class', []):
            continue
        elif isinstance(c, Tag):
            clear(c)
        else:
            c.replace_with('')

clear(soup.select_one('div.a'))

print('-' * 80)

# print soup after clearing:
print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div class="a">
  ...stuff...
  <div>
    ...stuff....
    <div class="my_class_of_interest">
      ....several levels deeper...
    </div>
  ..stuff..
  </div>
  ...stuff..
</div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="a">
 <div>
  <div class="my_class_of_interest">
   ....several levels deeper...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, using lxml:

```
import lxml.html as lh
interest = """your html above"""
doc = lh.fromstring(interest)
retain = ''
for d in doc.xpath('//*'):
    if d.attrib and d.attrib.values()[0]=="my_class_of_interest":
           retain += d.text
    d.text =""
    d.tail=""
for target in doc.xpath('//div[@class="my_class_of_interest"]'):
    target.text=retain
print(lh.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output:

```
<div class="a"><div><div class="my_class_of_interest">
      ....several levels deeper...
      </div></div></div>
```